# WebSocket sharing port 443

Tags: ssl, websocket, wss

I am finding that trying to connect to my SSL websocket server works fine over WIFI, but when I try it over cellular it wont connect. I had read that it may be because I'm not running it on port 443.

What is the best way to run my websocket server on port 443 on a server that's already running Apache? I see that this is possible using programs such as nginx, but I haven't found any clean instructions on how to do this. Basically I want wss connections to go to my websocket server, and https to go to Apache, and all port 80 connections are left alone. What's the easiest way to do this?

Also, I'm running this on a VPS with multiple IPs, is it possible to have one of those IPs set up for my WebSocket server only without Apache?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using Nginx or Apache?

Comment: I'm using Apache for the Webserver and I wrote the WebSocket server in .NET CORE. I'm not currently using Nginx

Comment: If you're already running a web server on :443, you need to proxy those websocket requests through that server and on to your websocket server.

Comment: Yeah that's what I read, am looking for recommendations on the best/easiest solution to do this and some clear instructions on how to set it up like this. I've seen a bunch or articles on this but nothing exactly like what I'm looking for. Thanks